# How to create share and grant multiple permissions on Windows8 using script

Tags: powershell, windows-8, get-wmiobject

Requirement : I want to create a script to manage share and assign multiple permissions on windows 8 machine using **NET SHARE** command. It doesn't support SMB modules( **New-SmbShare and Set-Smbshare**) as this module is not compatible with Windows 8. So I found below command to create share and set permission. Please find the below powershell script:

```sh
$ErrorActionPreference="continue" 
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Temp\Smb.csv 
foreach ($details in $csv) 
{ 
    $Name="$($details.Name)" 
    $Path="$($details.Path)" 
    $User="$($details.user)" 
    $Permission="$($details.Permission)" 
    NET SHARE $NAME=$PATH \grant:$User,$Permission 
}
```

To Grant Multiple Shares:

`NET SHARE NAME=PATH \grant:User:Permission \grant:User:Permission`

Problem :- How to grant below multiple permissions to multiple users for one single path that is mentioned in CSV file. How to pass below CSV file in the above command.
Please find the below csv file

```
Path, Share-Name, User, Permission
C:/Temp/April, April, ABC, Read
C:/Temp/April, April, DEF, Change
C:/Temp/April, April, GEH, Full
C:/Temp/April, April, IJK, Read
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$details.'Share-Name'`? Also, besides using the comma after the user, I don't see and issue with the code. You getting any errors?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala When code starts using loop, This code is only working for 1st line only. For 2nd line, it is showing error "Name has already been shared". I want to grant permissions to multiple users. This is only working for single user. How to pass multiple \grant permissions in variable.